# JS how does function in parentacess work?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have two variables a & b function below swap their values

```
 b = (function(a){return a})(a, a=b)
```

I would to know what does this part of code

```
(a, a=b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a, a=b)` calls the function with two arguments. A classical immediately-invoked function expression.

In the arguments list, the `a` value is passed as the first argument (which will then be returned by the function and ultimately be assigned to `b`), and the assignment expression `a=b` (which writes the `b` value into the `a` variable) is passed as the second argument (which the function ignores).